# Distribute multiple items evenly throughout a dynamic space

Tags: android, layout, button, menu, center

I'm designing a layout that has several buttons and I want the buttons to be all evenly spaced in the menu, and I'm trying to find a way to do this without using any numeric values. If the screen is rotated or the screen size differs I want it all to still be centered.

Here's an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY88p.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a weighted LinearLayout. Check out the [LinearLayout Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html) for an example.

Comment: Wouldn't that bunch all the buttons together in the middle, or does that evenly spread them out?

Comment: Using additional "empty" views between the buttons will spread them out in proportion to the weight given.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example. it's adding items programatically.
[github](https://github.com/SwordArtist/DynamicEvenSpreadingView)